# Wrong IP address present when connecting from localhost to localhost

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mysql, localhost

I have a Linux server with Ubuntu installed on it.
When I connecting to some service (MySQL, apache, icecast for example) from the same machine at address `127.0.0.1`, they all show that I connected from my local address (`10.10.x.x`) instead of `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).
It causes problems with connecting to MySQL database (because of restrictions which allow connect only from localhost) and just looks ugly.

What's the reason of this problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, problem was hiding in another place of the system. I had this rule for `iptables` which I just copied from some manual:

```
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This rule was set to allow NAT for accessing clients to Internet. This rule wasn't limited with any conditions, so requests from localhost to localhost was NAT'ed and applications was detecting wrong IP. After addition of some conditions (source IP addresses) to this rule I got right 127.0.0.1 as clients' IP addresses:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, MySQL historically uses localhost as a socket based connection, instead of ip. You will not see 127.0.0.1 or localhost until you don't connect by socket.
(Yes it's wrong)